# How to solve this MySQL Puzzle?

Tags: mysql, sql

Current sql:

```
SELECT
    clientId,
    groupID, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT clientId) AS visitors,
    ROUND(AVG(price),2) AS price
FROM  
(
    SELECT `devices`.*, MAX(`url`.price) AS price 
    FROM `devices`, `url` 
    WHERE `devices`.visited_url = `url`.website
) devices
GROUP BY `devices`.groupID
```

- url table has many website with each prices.
- devices table are records where people visit a certain website using mobile and that website exist in url table.
- I want to get the average of visited url in device

Device table data:

```
id   clientId   device   groupId  visited_url
 1   client1    samsung      123  fb.com
 2   client1    samsung      123  google.com
 3   client1    samsung      123  fb.com
 4   client1    samsung      123  fb.com
 5   client2    iphone       123  google.com
 6   client2    iphone       123  google.com
```

Url table data:

```
id     website    price
 1     fb.com        $1
 2     google.com    $2
```

I want to get the prices of visited_url

Tried this method:

`ROUND(AVG(MAX(value)),2) AS value`

And got this Error:

> `Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function`

The question is: How to combine `ROUND()`, `AVG()` and `MAX()` in one line?

The result that I want is:

```
clientId  groupID   website     visitors  price
client1       123   fb.com             3     $3 (avg)
client1       123   google.com         1     $2 (avg)
client2       123   google.com         2     $4 (avg)
```

Comment: What do you think `AVG(MAX(value))` would accomplish? `MAX(value)` gets the highest `value`. `AVG(value)` gets `sum(value) / number of rows`. What would `AVG(MAX(value))` do?

Comment: Provide the whole query with some sample data and what is your expected result. Please define all the things and present the question in a more clear way.

Comment: Getting the average of a single value would (in practice) simply be the same thing as getting the value itself. However, considering you'd never need to do that, it makes sense for MySQL to throw an error.

Comment: OP Do you mean that you want to group by a value, get an average for each group, and then get the max of those averages? Or something like that? Please include your query in your question and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Okay guys, Ill update my question with data. Please wait.

Comment: I have updated my question. @john

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you want from the input you have provided above?

Comment: OP, if you provide a sample output I can give you an answer.

Comment: @ObsidianAge updated

Comment: client1 / fb.com / $3? Isn't that the price from the URLs table * 3?

Comment: @john because we average it. We add all fb.com in the same client then divide by 3, which I didn't. But that should be the average. updated again

Comment: You mean the urls table already contains averages? At present it seems that you don't need averages at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168608/discussion-between-ken-dan-tinio-and-john).

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, you can't get the rounded average of a max()... Because the max is one thing, any average would be of itself. Now, what you can do is this...

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(value), 2), MAX(value) FROM tableName
```

Note: 'value' is your COLUMN name. 'tableName' is your table name obviously :)

Then you just have to bind it as 2 results... The first result would be the rounded average of the 'value' column. The second result is the rounded max of 'value' column.

But unfortunately, when you use MAX() you are saying "tell me what the maximum thing here is." This limits you to 1 result, but AVG() expects to get the average of a whole column, just like MAX() functions...so it has an invalid grouping to work with.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what OP wants. I reckon we should wait until he clarifies what is needed before answering.

Comment: hmmm... let me try this

Comment: Hope it helps Ken :) If it's what you wanted, please remember to mark as answer. If it's not what you want, can you please tell us more info :)

Comment: @Ken can you please update your question to clarify what you want?

Comment: @Nerdi.org not working but because of this I got an idea.

Comment: @john the thing that I want is get average of many row and then round it off, then get the max. Which I understand now that the result of average is only one which max is nonsense.

Comment: Well, I updated my query to not round the max. Where are you running this SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to simply want a `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`.  Based on the result that you want:

```
SELECT clientId, groupID, COUNT(*) AS visitors,
       ROUND(SUM(price), 2) AS price
FROM devices d JOIN
     url u
     ON d.visited_url = u.website
GROUP BY clientId, groupID;
```